# Aurora Borealis in Midrashim

Tags: midrash, mysticism-kabbalah, astronomy

We see many fascinating works of Hashem around the world and one of which is [Aurora Borealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora).

Do our midrashim or books on mysticism have anything to say about its origin or anything related to it?

Comment: Specifically the Auroras, or the magnetosphere in general, which the Auroras are a side effect of the way it works? Also, there’s two Auroras: the Aurora Borealis near the north magnetic pole, and the Aurora Australis near the south magnetic pole. Did you mean to ask specifically about the Northern Lights, or both of them?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj0Tj8dnrYw

Comment: Either one of them

Answer (score 1):

Shimon Fogel in Kovetz Beit Aharon V'Yisrael [suggests](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=171&book=142886) that when Rav Huna the son of Rav Yehoshua said "It is merely that vilon, one of the firmaments, rips and furls and the light of the next firmament is seen, and this appears like a comet" ([Brachot 58b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Berakhot.58b.11.4?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=en&p2=Berakhot.58b.11&lang2=en&w2=all&lang3=en)), he may have been referring to the aurora.

Avraham Halevi in Hachinuch Be'otiyotav [writes](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=180&book=617838) that the verse "And the knowledgeable will be radiant like the bright expanse of sky, and those who lead the many to righteousness will be like the stars forever and ever." - which in Hebrew has the phrase "Zohar Haraki'ah" - may be referring to the Aurora (in modern Hebrew called Zohar Hatzafon or Zohar Hakotev).

Sefaria's English translation of Malbim interpret his [commentary on Iyov 38:24-25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malbim_on_Job.38.24.1-25.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as referring to the aurora.

Comment: I don't see these modern writers bringing credible explanations of their sources.

Comment: @Mordechai Their explanations are based on the meaning of the words in the text.

Comment: And I strongly disagree with each translation.

Comment: @Mordechai That's perfectly okay; we're all entitled to our opinion. However, now I'm curious. If, hypothetically, Rashi or one of the other classic commentators would have said exactly the same thing, word for word, nothing more and nothing less, as one of these men, what would you have said?